# Azure AD B2C personalised content after login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm building a web app (SPA) that is a case management system. Each user (mainly external to organisation) has a case on the system. I've been told by an architect we should be able to use Azure AD B2C to allow the users to login on this so I've been investigating this.

From what I can see I will get a token back from B2C saying the user is authenticated. What I don't understand is what use is that? Ok the user is authenticated but I have no idea who they are i.e. I will need to identify their case ref somehow so I can bring back their details...

If i was doing this in the old days when they login they'd be checked against a user table then their ID would be used to get their case details .. a token and data object would be returned from an api.. job done

I don't see how this would work in Azure AD B2C... am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JWT that is returned contains a configurable set of claims.

You can use these to identify the user. Typically, this would be email or UPN.

In your case, you need a userID. If this isn't one of the supported attributes, you can use an extension attribute to store it.

B2C can also call an API (if you use custom policies) so you could call an API to get the userID from e.g. a table and then return it as an extension attribute in the JWT.

Comment: I thought there must be something like that but couldn't find a good example

Comment: Can you recommend any good resources for confidently understanding and using custom policies?  I get scared and overwhelmed every time I look at these official articles:  [Azure AD B2C custom policy overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview) and [Tutorial: Create user flows and custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).  I think one of the reasons is that I find the XML file format intimidating and confusing.

Comment: There are some courses listed here (https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-custom-policies-in-azure-ad-b2c-eb63b508a075) under "Training" plus a link to a tutorial I wrote.